# Maven project how to call setter function in html?

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

i haven a maven project and i'm sending object of user to html and i want to use setter function of this object to fill the attribute in the object

how could i do that ?  or is that even possible !

This what i tried

my html code

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/view/Register}" th:object="${user}"
    method="post">
    <p> Name: <input type="text" th:field="${user.getAccount().setUserName()}" required="required" /> </p>
    <p> Email : <input type="text" th:field="${user.getAccount().setEmail()}" required="required" /> </p>
    <p> Password : <input type="text" th:field="${user.getAccount().setPassword()}" required="required" /> </p>
    <p> Profile :<input type="file" name="picture" /> </p>
    <p> Male : <input type="radio" th:field="${user.getAccount().setGender()}" value="Male" checked="true" /> Female : <input type="radio" th:field="${user.getAccount().setGender()}"
            value="Female" />
    </p>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Note : 
User is interface 
i send object " User user = new Student () " 
When Student is class implements User

Comment: Why you are calling setter method, if it's a model entity of spring, you can directly access it in your view, like `th:field = "${user.account.userName}"`

Comment: actually user is interface so i couldn't do that  i send User u = new Student () and student is class implements User